# Passando parametros de array para array

Tags: javascript

Preciso pesquisar dentro de 2 arrays de acordo com o parametro passado pelo primeiro array, exemplo:

Preciso varrer o array "profiles" pegando cada id e pesquisando nos outros dois:

```
const profiles = [
    {
      id: 1,
      userID: '1',
      favoriteMovieID: '1',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      userID: '2',
      favoriteMovieID: '1',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      userID: '4',
      favoriteMovieID: '5',
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      userID: '5',
      favoriteMovieID: '2',
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      userID: '3',
      favoriteMovieID: '5',
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      userID: '6',
      favoriteMovieID: '4',
    },
  ];

const users = {
    1: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Jane Cruz',
      userName: 'coder',
    },
    2: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Matthew Johnson',
      userName: 'mpage',
    },
    3: {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Autumn Green',
      userName: 'user123',
    },
    4: {
      id: 4,
      name: 'John Doe',
      userName: 'user123',
    },
    5: {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Lauren Carlson',
      userName: 'user123',
    },
    6: {
      id: 6,
      name: 'Nicholas Lain',
      userName: 'user123',
    },
  };

  const movies = {
    1: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Planet Earth 1',
    },
    2: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Selma',
    },
    3: {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Million Dollar Baby',
    },
    4: {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Forrest Gump',
    },
    5: {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Get Out',
    },
  };
```

Como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: Amigo, só existe um array, e é o array profiles. Os outros dois são objetos(apesar de objetos e arrays serem basicamente a mesma coisa em JS).
De qualquer forma, pode especificar melhor o que você quer? Como quer que saia o resultado?

Comment: Preciso que saia : "Jane Cruz", com id "1", assiste o filme "Planet Earth 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sabendo que Arrays e Objetos são bem semelhantes em JS, você pode se referir a uma propriedade de um objeto usando `[]` e pondo o nome dentro, e vice e versa. Exemplo:

```
var obj = {
   prop1 = 1,
   prop2 = 2
}
console.log(obj[prop1]); // "1"
```

E vice e versa.

```
var array = ['um', 'dois', 'três']
console.log(array.2); // "três"
// Conforme apontado nos comentários, este codigo geraria um erro pois uma propriedade não pode iniciar em número, mas a lógica é basicamente essa.
```

Após entender isso, é fácil a resolução do problema:

```
profiles.forEach(function(item, index) { //Itera sobre a array profiles
  let nome = users[item.userID].name; //pega o nome da pessoa usando o userID
  let id = users[item.userID].id; //pega o ID da pessoa na tabela de users
  let filme = movies[item.favoriteMovieID].name; //pega o filme favorito usando o id

  console.log(nome + ', com id ' + id + ', assiste o filme ' + filme);
})
```

Se preferir ter entre aspas os nomes, só adicionar na string e concatenar, assim:

```
console.log('"' +nome + '", com id "' + id + '", assiste o filme "' + filme + '"');
```

Comment: Apenas uma correção: `console.log(array.2); // "dois"` seria `// três`. Mas não se pode ter um identificador que comece com números, então este código vai dar um erro. teria que ser `array[2]`

Comment: Bem apontado, vou editar. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Como as chaves das variáveis `movies` e `users` são os ids dos mesmo, você pode usar a `profile.userID` e `profile.favoriteMovieID` para buscar diretamente nos objetos.

No exemplo abaixo eu percorro `profiles` acrescentando as informações no objeto baseado no id do objeto.

```js
const profiles = [
    {
        id: 1,
        userID: '1',
        favoriteMovieID: '1',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        userID: '2',
        favoriteMovieID: '1',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        userID: '4',
        favoriteMovieID: '5',
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        userID: '5',
        favoriteMovieID: '2',
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        userID: '3',
        favoriteMovieID: '5',
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        userID: '6',
        favoriteMovieID: '4',
    },
];

const users = {
    1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Jane Cruz',
        userName: 'coder',
    },
    2: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Matthew Johnson',
        userName: 'mpage',
    },
    3: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Autumn Green',
        userName: 'user123',
    },
    4: {
        id: 4,
        name: 'John Doe',
        userName: 'user123',
    },
    5: {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Lauren Carlson',
        userName: 'user123',
    },
    6: {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Nicholas Lain',
        userName: 'user123',
    },
};

const movies = {
    1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Planet Earth 1',
    },
    2: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Selma',
    },
    3: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Million Dollar Baby',
    },
    4: {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Forrest Gump',
    },
    5: {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Get Out',
    },
};

for (let i=0, l=profiles.length ; i < l ; i++) {
    let profile = profiles[i];

    profile.user = users[profile.userID] || `Usuário com id (${profile.userID}) não encontrado.`;
    profile.favoriteMovie = movies[profile.favoriteMovieID] || `Filme com id (${profile.userID}) não encontrado.`;
    
    console.log(profile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, acho que desta forma você consegue recuperar o usuário e o filme que pertence a cada perfil:

```js
profiles.forEach(profile => {
    
    let usuario = users.find( user => user.id == profile.userID );
    let filme = movies.find( movie => movie.id == profile.favoriteMovieID);

    console.log(usuario.name + ' assiste ' + filme.name);
});
```